# Wordpress and AJAX - output from array

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress, output

With a plugin I'm adding a shortcode that puts a form on a page. On a server I have this function:

```
        function ajax_calc(){
    // with the POST  

            if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'ajax_calc'){
    //clearing and adapting input string
                $width      = str_replace(',','.',trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['width'])));    

                $length     = str_replace(',','.',trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['length'])));  

                $height     = str_replace(',','.',trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['height'])));

                $m_rul      = str_replace(',','.',trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['m_rul'])));     

                $k_zap      = str_replace(',','.',trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['k_zap'])));

    // an error if not a float number 
                if(!(float)$width || $width ==''){     
                    echo implode(array('loadmsgerr'=>'Error! Width should be number only!'));

                }
                elseif(!(float)$length || $length ==''){
                    echo implode(array('loadmsgerr'=>'Error! Lenght should be number only!'));

                }
                elseif(!(float)$height || $height ==''){
                    echo implode(array('loadmsgerr'=>'Error! Height should be number only!'));

                }
                else{
    // return result     
                    $Perimeter = ($width + $length) * 2 ; // 
                    $Square =  $Perimeter * $height;      //                                    // there will be other calculations...

                    $it_test = 10*$k_zap + $m_rul;

//     here we have an ARRAY with data
                    $answers = array('S' => $Square, 'P' => $Perimeter, 'it_test' => $it_test);                      
                    echo json_encode($answers);
                            }
                    }
            }
```

Next, I have a JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
// catch a click 
    jQuery('#calc #form_calc_id').on('submit', function(e){
        jQuery('#calc .result').show().text(ajax_calc_object.loadingmessage);//Обработка...
//AJAX with POST on url. DataType is json for array        
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_calc_object.ajaxurl,
            data: { //data from our form
                'action': 'ajax_calc', //
                'width': jQuery('#calc #width').val(), 
                'length':jQuery('#calc #length').val(),
                'height': jQuery('#calc #height').val(),                            
//                'security': jQuery('#security').val()
                'm_rul': jQuery('#pa_м-в-рулоне').text(),
                'k_zap': jQuery('#pa_k-zap').text(),

            },
            success: function(data){
                var resperr = data.loadmsgerr;

                if(!resperr){//if its all clear
                    json.parse(data);
                    jQuery('#calc .result').html(data.S + data.P); //put the answer to .result taget div

                }
                else{
                    jQuery('#calc .result').text(resperr); //or an error message
                }

            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {//console log
                if (xhr.status != 0) {
                    var msg = ' (' + xhr.status + ') ';
                    if (textStatus) msg += ': ' + textStatus;
                    if (xhr.status < 200) {
                        msg = 'AJAX Informational ' + msg;
                    } else if (xhr.status < 300) {
                        msg = 'AJAX Success ' + msg;
                    } else if (xhr.status < 400) {
                        msg = 'AJAX Redirection ' + msg;
                    } else if (xhr.status < 500) {
                        msg = 'AJAX Client Error' + msg;
                    } else {
                        msg = 'AJAX Server Error' + msg;
                    }
                    console.log(msg);
                } else {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Trouble is that i have no result on my page.
Console says:

> AJAX Success  (200) : parsererror

From my function I see this:

> {"S":"","P":"","it_test":"19"}0

I think that its all from 0 in the end of json string. But I cant get why it's appear there..

Comment: can you post your php code as well?

Comment: function is in the WordPress plugin file, its too large for read here.. besides, now I have the answer)

Answer (score 0):

If we put `wp_die()` in the end of the ajax_calc() function, 0 will not appear.